# I don't understand the toString method. How can I print the contents of an object?

Tags: java, object, tostring

Generally in java, I know that if we try to print multiple objects (for example objects named Joe, Steve, Richard) like that

```
System.out.println(Joe);
System.out.println(Steve);
System.out.println(Richard);
```

the outcome will be the memory location not the object itself. But if I invoke a toString method on only one of them, it will print the object's contents normally and that's what I fail to understand.

Also, if the toString method is a pre-defined method, why do I have to re-write it in my code?
Thank you.

```
public class Time {
int Hours;
int Minutes;
int Seconds;

public Time(int h, int m, int s){
    Hours = h;
    Minutes = m;
    Seconds = s;
}
public Time(){
    Hours = 0;
    Minutes = 0;
    Seconds = 0;
}
public int hours ( )
 {
return Hours ;
 }
public int minutes ( )
{
return Minutes ;
 }
public int seconds ( )
 {
return Seconds;
 }
 public void addhour ( )
 {
if ( Hours == 23)
{
Hours = 0 ;
}
else Hours++;
}
public void addminute ( )
{
if (Minutes == 59)
    {
Minutes = 0 ;
addhour ( ) ;
   }
else Minutes++;
 }
public void addsecond ( )
{
if ( Seconds == 59)
{
Seconds = 0 ;
addminute ( ) ;
 }
 else Seconds++;
 }
 public String toString(){
return "Time now is " + Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;
    }
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Time t = new Time (23, 59, 59);
    Time r = new Time (22, 59, 59);
System.out.println(t) ;
System.out.println(r) ;
t.addhour( );
System.out.println(t) ;
t.addminute( );
System.out.println(t) ;
t.addsecond( ) ;
System.out.println(t.toString());
                   }


 }
```

the output is :

Time now is 23:59:59

Time now is 22:59:59

Time now is 0:59:59

Time now is 1:0:59

Time now is 1:1:0

Comment: "if I invoke a toString method on only one of them, it will print the object's contents normally" - please construct a test-case that demonstrates this.

Comment: toString doesn't print anything at all. it merely returns a String based representation of the instance, and that representation can be printed.

Comment: You have overriden `toString` so when you print the object, that code is called. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You have two things Object and Attributes of Objects if Joe (a person) is Object than height,width,etc. are his Attributes.

```
System.out.println(Joe);<---it'll print reference

System.out.println(Joe.height);<----It will print attribute assigned to Object
```

Now point is you don't need to call `toString()` if you are using `System.out.println()` because `println()` do it implicitly for you.

It happens something like this

```
object.attribute
```

goes into memory to find reference takes that reference to associate it's attributes and `println()` calls `toString()` and prints value.

---

Your `toString()` method is `overriding` the actual method which is there in [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class because `Object` is Super class of all classes.

```
public String toString(){
return "Time now is " + Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;
    }
```

---

*One other way.*

If you want to get all attributes of Object you can create method

```
public String method(YourClass o)
{
return o.hour+":"+o.minute+":"+o.second;
}
```

Comment: But how do I print a whole object, not just an attribute?

Comment: You are doing exactly what you should you need to override `toString` or you can create method which takes Object as an argument and returns String of all attribute of that object.

Answer (score 0):

> the outcome will be the memory location not the object itself.

No if you have not overridden toString() method in your class default toString() method of Object class is used. i.e

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

which prints the classname along with it's hash value.

> Also, if the toString method is a pre-defined method, why do I have to re-write it in my code?

It's called overriding and you do it so that when you print the object your custom toString() is called and not the default one which prints class name and it's hash.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a way to print the internal values of the Object. If you don't re-write it will display the default string representation of the object, which usually is meaningless.

It's not mandatory, but it's usually useful when you're debugging your code OR when you are printing your data in the console.

Answer (score 0):

toString() is predefined for all objects and defaults to the behaviour you describe.

You need to redefine it because your desired behaviour is unique yo you as a programmer. Should object Joe print "Joe", "Joe Beluchi" or "Joe, aged 23years, living in New York".

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would have to override ToString method and customize it in order to print the information you need.

For instance, if you objects were persons, you could override ToString (in Person class) as following:

```
@Override public class Person {

 return "Person{" + "Name=" + this.name + ",
               Surname=" + this.surname + ",
               Date of birth=" + this.birth + '}';


}
```